# Having object with a property which has array of numbers, need to sum

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, properties, sum

I have an data file, where I have a information about 5 people.
I made a class `Person` with different `properties`.
One of the properties is called `range`.

```
public int[] range { get; set; }
```

When I read the file my range accepts all the range values from the file, but in  windows form I need to show the sum of the numbers in the array.
example: for the first person I have 2,3,4 and in the table in the column of range, the user need to see the number 9.
Thanks in advance for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Sum of your range:

I would create a seperate property called rangeSum or something that would be defined as the following:

```
public int RangeSum
{
   get{ return range.Sum();}
}
```

No setter needed as you shouldn't need to set this property because it is dependent on the range.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
int sumValue= range.Sum();
```

Comment: ty for the fast reply, but I missed smth to add. The file was a json one and I did a Deserialize in order to use the class Person and be able to show the information in table. So everything is stored in List<Person> model. I am binding the data to Repeater control and can't find the way to create a row in the table which accept the sum of the range property. So where exactly I should use this int sumValue= range.Sum(); in the code behind or in the class file?

Comment: @КристианКънев If you follow my solution above couldn't you just bind the RangeSum Property to the Repeater control and use it like you would any other property?

Comment: @cstopher its working perfect !! Thanks for the help and the fast reply.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to save all the values for each Person, maybe in an array.
After that you just sum the numbers and save it in range.

```
personOne.range=arrayOfValues[].Sum();
```